# jQuery Input Colour Changes Not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get my input fields (associated by class) to change colour when they have content.

This is working, but removing the class isn't activating properly, and I'm unsure why. If I enter content into the first, then second input, delete the content from the first, the class is removed, however if I delete the content from the second before the first, the background remains blue.

I can't use the textboxes Id's as they're already in use.

**JS Code:**

```
 $('.checkFiller').on('change', function () {
     if ($('.checkFiller').length > 0) {
         $(this).addClass('allFiller');
     }
     if ($('.checkFiller').val() == '' || $('.checkFiller').val() == 0 || $('.checkFiller').val() == null) {
         $(this).removeClass('allFiller');
     }
 });
```

Here is a jsfiddle to demo my frustration - what am I doing wrong?

https://jsfiddle.net/qwgj77tm/1/

Comment: if ($('.checkFiller').length > 0) = this will always be true... You want it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `this` to get the one you are editing use `.hasClass()` and `.length` to acheive this

```js
 $('.checkFiller').on('change', function () {
     if($(this).val().length==0){
      $(this).removeClass('allFiller');
     }else $(this).addClass('allFiller');
 });
```

```css
.allFiller {
    background-color: #333366;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="checkFiller">
<input class="checkFiller">
<input class="checkFiller">
```

Comment: @PurpleSmurph Please accept as an answer if you think the solution worked for you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your references from `$('.checkFiller')` to `$(this)` in the on:

```
 $('.checkFiller').on('change', function () {
     if ($(this).length > 0) {
         $(this).addClass('allFiller');
     }
     if ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == 0 || $(this).val() == null) {
         $(this).removeClass('allFiller');
     }
 });
```

As is, you're checking the first input with the class, rather the one that has changed.